Python Pandas - Data Correction with Correction Files
i usuallly have large Datasets where i need to correct some specific values in it.
I came up with a correction file, where i have a varous conditions in a row with values i need to change based on that conditions.



Cond1
Cond2
Cond3
Value1




123
x
x
2


123
y
x
5



now i want to correct it in my dataframe and came up with something like:
for index, val in KORR.iterrows():

df.loc[(df.Cond1==val.iloc[0])&(df.Cond2==val.iloc[1])&(df.Cond3==val.iloc[2]),"Value1"]=val.iloc[3]

so i go over each row of my correction file and filter the data in my large df and correct each value.
This is quite slow eventough my Correction file has just like 100 rows.... is there a better way to do so?

Does this answer your question? Pandas, are there any faster ways to update values?

You can benefit from vectorized operations.
What we do is merge the initial dataset df and the correction file KORR with :
data = {
    'Cond1': [123, 123, 124],
    'Cond2': ['x', 'y', 'x'],
    'Cond3': ['x', 'x', 'y'],
    'Value1': [1, 2, 3]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

corrections = {
    'Cond1': [123, 123],
    'Cond2': ['x', 'y'],
    'Cond3': ['x', 'x'],
    'NewValue': [2, 5]
}
KORR = pd.DataFrame(corrections)

df_corrected = pd.merge(df, KORR, how='left', on=['Cond1', 'Cond2', 'Cond3'])

print(df_corrected) 

   Cond1 Cond2 Cond3  Value1  NewValue
0    123     x     x       1         2
1    123     y     x       2         5
2    124     x     y       3       NaN

The use of how='left' parameter in the pd.merge() function means that the merged dataframe will include all the rows from the left dataframe df, and the columns from both dataframes.
The use of on=['Cond1', 'Cond2', 'Cond3'] parameter means that where there are matches in the columns specified by the on parameter, the rows from the right dataframe KORR will be added to those from the left dataframe. If there is no match, the new columns from the right dataframe will contain NaN values for those rows.
Then we replace the values in Value1 column with the ones in NewValue if they are not NaN (thanks to .combine_first(df_corrected['Value1'])) :
df_corrected['Value1'] = df_corrected['NewValue'].combine_first(df_corrected['Value1'])

print(df_corrected)

   Cond1 Cond2 Cond3  Value1  NewValue
0    123     x     x       2         2
1    123     y     x       5         5
2    124     x     y       3       NaN

Finally we drop the NewValue column with :
df_corrected.drop(columns='NewValue', inplace=True)

print(df_corrected)

   Cond1 Cond2 Cond3  Value1
0    123     x     x       2
1    123     y     x       5
2    124     x     y       3

So really, you need 3 lines :
df_corrected = pd.merge(df, KORR, how='left', on=['Cond1', 'Cond2', 'Cond3'])
df_corrected['Value1'] = df_corrected['NewValue'].combine_first(df_corrected['Value1'])
df_corrected.drop(columns='NewValue', inplace=True)

